# Word choice for "solution" in a specific context

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

I can’t find the appropriate term to express something that one can try in order to fix a problem, but that is not guaranteed to work and might even lead to wasting resources.

The word “solution” seems inappropriate since it entails that what I will try is going to work. It has a positive connotation I believe.

Here is an example sentence with a context for the word I am looking for:

> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on unfruitful *(insert a replacement for the word “solutions” here)*.

In this example, even the word “unfruitful” seems a bit awkward to use in a formal context.

I am looking for a word preferably used in scientific journals and other academic publications.

Comment: To avoid wasting money on lower probability approaches...

Comment: How about 'attempts'?!

Comment: as @user58319 mentioned,  "solution attempt" is used in academic paper see https://scholar.google.fr/scholar?hl=fr&q=%22solution+attempt%22&btnG=&lr=

Comment: I was not convinced with the word "attempt" alone as a replacement. However, combining it with the word "solution" seems to work and apparently, from the link you sent, it is used in academic papers. I was hoping for a one word obscure yet popular replacement but I guess this would work too

Comment: An attempt is something you make. It’s not an attempt until you attempt it.  An approach, on the other hand, can be contemplated and discarded and itls still an approach.

Comment: Just a comment on your question rather than an answer. A methodology is usually 'adopted' rather than 'done', this is because a methodology is a formal approach to doing something rather than a series of actions leading to an actual result. In this sense a methodology is similar to a protocol.

Comment: Does 'Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on unfruitful (insert a replacement for the word “solutions” here).' make sense? It seems like 'We did X because we knew A, B, C ... wouldn't work.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it's a methodology that helps in picking up the correct set of solutions by identifying the exact source of a problem thereby eliminating any incorrect solution attempt/approach whatever you may call it... Without going into details, yes, I believe it does make sense.

Comment: Perhaps 'X indicated that attempted solutions along the lines of A, B, C ... were non-starters / very unlikely to succeed....'

Comment: If you are not comfortable with *approach*, consider "undertaking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check ***edeavour/endeavor***.

I have taken the liberty of changing a couple of other words too in your example.

> Methodology X was *adopted* in order to avoid wasting resources on
> *unpromising* ***endeavors***.

ODO:

> **[endeavour](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/endeavour)** (US **endeavor**)
>
> NOUN
>
> **1** An attempt to achieve a goal.
>
> [WITH INFINITIVE] ‘an endeavour to reduce serious injury’
>
> ‘He has also opposed endeavors to reduce greenhouse-gas emissions.’
>
> ‘The group standards mechanism in the bill will reduce compliance
> costs, and it is an endeavour to reduce those costs.’

Answer (score 0):

I am going to start by dropping *unfruitful*. How about one of the following:

> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on
>   *possible* solutions
>
> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on
>   *potential* solutions.
>
> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on
>   *proposed* solutions.
>
> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on
>   *plausible* solutions.
>
> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on *trial*
>   solutions.
>
> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on
>   *uncertain* solutions.

Each of the suggested adjectives (there are other possibilities) carries some degree of uncertainty, with some implying more uncertainty than others. You could take your pick based on the degree of uncertainty acceptable in your context.

"*Uncertain* solutions" may be a good bet. *Uncertain* works better in a formal context that *unfruitful*.

If you want to keep *unfruitful*, you might want to consider reordering the words as follows:

> Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on
>   *potentially* unfruitful *approaches*.

Of course, there are other possibilities if you want to take the *unfruitful* approach.

Answer (score 0):

the word 'Option' is a good fit here:

Methodology X was done in order to avoid wasting resources on unfruitful options